Ubuntu 24.04 LTS / Dell T460 / Cannort recover fron Suspend mode
In 22.04, the suspend feature was working perfectly, without any issue.
Since I applied 24.04, the Suspend option works, but the active mode cannot be reactivated.
I tried the power button, the CTRL-ALT-SUPP sequence, even Fn-CTRL-ALT-SUPP. No success, I need to power off the PC and restart.

The /var/log/kern.log file shows that the suspend action is detected, applied and then the forced restart. There is no activity related to tries I do to reactivate the system in the middle.
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

~$ uname -a
Linux machine-ThinkPad-T460 6.9.1-060901-generic #202405171038 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri May 17 10:55:28 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What can be done, please?
The keyborad setting for the power button is:
gsettings list-recursively | grep -E 'sleep|suspend*'
org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files initial-sleep 15
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend-static ['XF86Sleep']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'

Any clue?
